# Can I merge a resource XAML dictionary in a single page's resources?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

My application has a single page with an explicit dark background (dark image), but the rest of the application uses the system colors. Is there a way to use the merged dictionary technique outlined [here](http://www.designersilverlight.com/2011/01/17/theme-forcing-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight/), but only for a single page, in order to not have to explicitly set the colors (and styles for TextBox controls, etc) on each control one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique you have linked to is not limited to the App.xaml.  It can be used in any definition of a `ResourceDictionary`.  Everywhere you see a `Resources` property an implicit `ResourceDictionary` is created for you when it is accessed.  However in all these places you can also explicitly define one.  This will allow you to also manipulate its `MergedDictionaries` property.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDicitonary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="urlToAnotherXamlFile" />
            </ResourceDicitonary.MergedDictionaries> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    .... Content ....
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I initially tried on the PhoneApplicationPage directly, which failed because I had other entries with keys. I didn't realize it was possible on child controls.

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately, merging this at the page/control level does not apply to the TextBox (and probably others?). I'd have to restyle each one. :(